# Controller returning HttpResponseMessage not setting content type correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpresponsemessage

I have the following code in a controller to return a stream which is an Excel File to download on the client side:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
MemoryStream memStream = ReportExporter.ExportReport(analystReport);

response.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = saveAsFileName;

return response;
```

When I make the request on the client side it simply gives me back the wrapper of the response message:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.xlsx
}
```

I believe this maybe due to the headers coming back as text as this is what I see in Chrome:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I can't work out what is happening here having tried various things.

Comment: What's the type of `response`?

Comment: Sorry a bit of code was missing added it back, it's a HttpResponseMessage

Comment: you should normally include the controller method declaration, too. it determines/indicates the interface required of your code.

Comment: The fact that you're seeing the serialized representation of the `HttpResponseMessage` means that you instantiate it incorrectly, return it incorrectly or both. Please show the action method signature as @montewhizdoh indicates.

Comment: @CodeCaster it must be HttpResponseMessage, but if he doesnt show us, its harder to communicate the solution because that is part of the problem, as you say.

Comment: @montewhizdoh well you can return an `HttpResponseMessage` from a WebAPI controller, just not from MVC - or at least, depending on the MVC version. With MVC 6 you can.

Comment: @CodeCaster once again, thanks, I didnt think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
// Copy file to byte array
byte[] file = new byte[memStream.Length];
memStream.Read(file, 0, file.Length);

// Send file
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + saveAsFileName);
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.BinaryWrite(file);
Response.End();

// Return success
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

`Response` is a `Controller` property, so you don't need to create any `HttpResponseMessage` object.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down?

This solved my issue thanks although I changed the conversion to bytes bit slightly as you version gave me the right number of bytes but it gave me a huge list of NULLs. I used: byte[] bytes = memStream.ToArray(); then the rest of your code works perfectly thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, but I will show you mine. Instead of HttpResponseMessage you can just do FileStreamResult. And You dont need to instantiate HttpResponseMessage, its already part of the controller method. This is how I would start to try to fix your code. Remember to use FileStreamResult instead.

```
    public FileStreamResult DownloadExcel(???analystReport????)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = ReportExporter.ExportReport(analystReport);

        return new FileStreamResult(memStream , "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
    }
```

Comment: _"Watch out for the last line, its untested"_ - yeah, you can't return a binary Excel file as an ASCII string like that.

Comment: how would you convert the memStream to a string?

Comment: Wrong question. The question is "why". It's a binary file, so you should serve it as binary. It is unclear why you think serving it as string would solve the issue.

Comment: ok good point, I shoulnt be so lazy and unclear. i switch to a more native interface. thanks!